# Apply keyword extraction model to a Spark DataFrame column that contains text

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp, nltk, keyword

Imagine I have a Spark DataFrame `planet` that contains 2 columns - `id` and `description`:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mercury is the closest planet to the Sun. The smallest planet in the Solar System, Mercury has no natural satellites. The dominant geological features are impact craters or basins with ejecta blankets, the remains of early volcanic activity including magma flows, and lobed ridges or rupes that were probably produced by a period of contraction early in the planet's history. |
| 2 | Venus is close in size to Earth and has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core and evidence of internal geological activity. Venus is the hottest planet mainly due to the amount of greenhouse gases in the atmosphere. Venus has no magnetic field that would prevent depletion of its substantial atmosphere, which suggests that its atmosphere is being replenished by volcanic eruptions. |

I want to apply different keyword extraction models and for each `id` extract keywords from corresponding text in the `description` column.

In almost all implementation examples, the models accept **text as a string**.
But how can I implement, for example, `keyBERT` model (look at the example [here](https://github.com/MaartenGr/KeyBERT)) processing `description` column instead of a simple text string?

In the output, I need to get my original dataframe extended with a new column with top n keywords found by the model:

| id | description | keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mercury is the closest planet to the Sun. The smallest planet in the Solar System, Mercury has no natural satellites. The dominant geological features are impact craters or basins with ejecta blankets, the remains of early volcanic activity including magma flows, and lobed ridges or rupes that were probably produced by a period of contraction early in the planet's history. | Mercury, Solar System, early volcanic activity, geological features, magma flows |
| 2 | Venus is close in size to Earth and has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core and evidence of internal geological activity. Venus is the hottest planet mainly due to the amount of greenhouse gases in the atmosphere. Venus has no magnetic field that would prevent depletion of its substantial atmosphere, which suggests that its atmosphere is being replenished by volcanic eruptions. | Venus, internal geological activity, thick silicate mantle, atmosphere, iron core |

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RDD.map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html) to apply a function to every element in your rdd.

I'm too lazy to actually install keyBERT, so I'll make up my own `extract_keywords` function to show an example.

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize(enumerate(("Mercury is the closest planet to the Sun. The smallest planet in the Solar System, Mercury has no natural satellites. The dominant geological features are impact craters or basins with ejecta blankets, the remains of early volcanic activity including magma flows, and lobed ridges or rupes that were probably produced by a period of contraction early in the planet's history.", "Venus is close in size to Earth and has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core and evidence of internal geological activity. Venus is the hottest planet mainly due to the amount of greenhouse gases in the atmosphere. Venus has no magnetic field that would prevent depletion of its substantial atmosphere, which suggests that its atmosphere is being replenished by volcanic eruptions."), start=1))

from heapq import nlargest

def extract_keywords(s):
    return nlargest(4, s.split(), key=len)

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], extract_keywords(x[1])))

print( rdd.collect() )
# [(1, "Mercury is ...", ['satellites.', 'contraction', 'geological', 'blankets,']),
#  (2, 'Venus is ...', ['atmosphere.', 'substantial', 'atmosphere,', 'replenished'])]
```

I'm not familiar with keyBERT, but from the example they show, I think one of the following two snippets could be appropriate:

```py
# EITHER USE SAME MODEL FOR EVERYONE
kw_model = KeyBERT()
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], kw_model.extract_keywords(x[1])))

# OR USE NEW MODEL FOR EACH ELEMENT
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], KeyBERT().extract_keywords(x[1])))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! However I tried to convert obtained RDD to a DataFrame and got a very long traceback with errors like these: ```TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))```, ```ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, can not infer schema")```, ```TypeError: Unable to infer the type of the field _3```, etc. Usually the output of keywords extraction models is a `list` (i.e. for each `id` I should get a separate `list` of values). Could this be a root cause of errors? How to handle this? Thank you!!

Comment: Below is the model output when I pass to the model the text string corresponding to `id` = 1 instead of `description` column. I guess I get the same output structure for each `id`: ('Solar System', 0.03331033477737768)
('closest planet', 0.03951565338618499)
('Sun', 0.05473220614236915)
('Mercury', 0.06029420653813042)
('planet', 0.09243513837653365). These are top 5 keywords and their scores.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "convert obtained RDD to a DataFrame". I've never manipulated a "DataFrame" in pyspark. Are you talking about a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Also, when do you get the error? Do you do rdd -> extract_keywords -> dataframe? Or rdd -> dataframe -> extract_keyword? In the latter case, you need to use DataFrame's functions to apply extract_keyword, not rdd.map.

Comment: When I do df -> rdd -> extract_keywords I don't get an error. Then I convert rdd to df as described [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/different-ways-to-create-a-spark-dataframe/), using the `toDF()` function and `.show()` to view the results, and get errors.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about dataframes. So, I just tried  `df = rdd.toDF()` and `rdd.show()`, and I don't get an error: https://pastebin.com/1WxrGUjV

Comment: Note that "df -> rdd -> rdd.map(extract_keywords) -> df" is probably not a good idea. There is probably a way to do what you want while keeping a dataframe, without using rdd. I just didn't know about dataframes before, so I assumed you had an rdd.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, then I'll look for a reason of my errors